# Not possible to install add-on on specifiek nodes

Tags: add-on, paas, jelastic

We have installed Telegraf add-on for almost all the nodes in Jelastic paas environment.
But for couple nodes we get the following message when we are trying to install the add-on:

[image]

We have read the documentation of Jelastic but could not find why we are getting this message. We have tested with a basic hello world manifest but even that was not possible to install, we do get the same message.

We have this problem for the following nodes:

- Custom
- PostgresSQL

Does anyone have experience with this message an how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telegraf add-on can be not supported by the type of node that it was tried to be installed on. That is why these node types could be absent in the manifest. In any way, if you want to try deploying the add-on on the mentioned node types (i.e. not to meet with the error "Add-on installation is not allowed for this node"), you may add along with already existing in the manifest node types these node types as well (more info from the Jelastic documentation is [here](https://docs.cloudscripting.com/creating-manifest/visual-settings/#target-nodes)):

```
targetNodes:
  nodeType:
  - postgresql
  - docker
```

In this case, there will be no such error as mentioned above, at least, but there are also no guarantees that the addon will be successfully installed and/or workable on these node types. For example, a custom node is based on the not supported by the add-on OS type

Answer (score 0):

Your Jelastic provider doesn't allow Telegraf to be installed on this type of node. You can ask them to allow that.
Thanks